# Symfony2 - SonataAdmin - Keep datetime when "Add new"

Tags: symfony, datetime, sonata-admin

I am designing a blog using Sonata Admin Bundle. The entity "News" is very simple (title, subtitle, content, creation date). I have a unique need.

The creation date should not be taken when I click on "Create", but when I click on "Add new".
In other words, I take the current datetime when I open the page with the form to create, not when I click on "Create".

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can set new DateTime to parameter 'data' for date form field in your Admin method configureFormFields.